# Resize EditText according to Font Size

Tags: android, android-edittext, resize, font-size, android-layoutparams

I am creating dynamic edit texts using below code:

```
final EditText rowTextView = new EditText(DragActivity.this);
rowTextView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
rowTextView.setHint("Type Here");
rowTextView.setSingleLine();
rowTextView.setTextColor(color);
rowTextView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
rowTextView.setBackground(null);
rowTextView.setText(enteredText);
rowTextView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, 44);
rowTextView.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE);
mDragLayer.addView(rowTextView);
rowTextView.setOnLongClickListener(DragActivity.this);
rowTextView.setOnTouchListener(DragActivity.this);
```

Onclick of a button I change the font size of the edit text with below code:

```
rowTextView.setTextSize(aNumberPicker.getValue());
```

The issue I am facing is that when the textsize is selected to a higher value, edit text does not resize. It remains at its original size. I would really appreciate if someone can tell me how to resize the edit text when the text size changes.

Comment: check this: https://viksaaskool.wordpress.com/2014/11/16/using-auto-resize-to-fit-edittext-in-android/

Comment: tried it already, but does not work in my case.

Comment: try to invoke rowTextView.setLayoutParams() after changing textsize

Comment: then comes a casting exception.